# Can't pull down chromedriver driver from google url

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdrivermanager-java

When attempting to pull down chrome drivers, the files cannot be located in https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/.  However, a quick search shows the driver file is actually in the google resource.

I've had success pulling down the driver using the mirror (http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver), but I have to be disconnected from my corporate vpn to do so, so this isn't ideal.

Regardless of vpn connection, the driver cannot be located in the google repository.  I've also tried removing the arch config, but have not been able to get webdrivermanager to locate the driver in the google directory.

TestNG and Java Snippet

```
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupClass() throws Exception {    
       WebDriverManager.chromedriver().arch32().setup();
       driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
```

Here's the console log and error message:

```
579 [main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Reading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/ to seek chromedriver
1000 [main] ERROR io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - chromedriver 76.0.3809.68 for WIN32 not found in https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
1000 [main] WARN io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - There was an error managing chromedriver 76.0.3809.68 (chromedriver 76.0.3809.68 for WIN32 not found in https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/) ... trying again using cache and mirror
16990 [main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Downloader - Downloading http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver/76.0.3809.68/chromedriver_win32.zip
18134 [main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Downloader - Extracting binary from compressed file chromedriver_win32.zip
18314 [main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\webdriver\chromedriver\win32\76.0.3809.68\chromedriver.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without forcing the architecture:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```